# I can not build VLCkit

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I am trying to build VLCkit with below instruction

 https://wiki.videolan.org/VLCKit/

 but I met an error which I do not understand as below

```
[[1;32minfo[0m] Preparing build dirs
Current branch master is up to date.
clang: error: no input files
clang: error: no input files
clang: error: no input files
[[1;32minfo[0m] Building tools
/Users/apple/01_workspace/02_video/VLCKit/buildVLCKit.sh: line 38: pushd: extras/tools: No such file or directory
```

Could you help me to explain what is this error, and how can I fix it?

I am using Mac OS Sierra version 10.12.6 and Xcode Version 8.3.3

Comment: this question could use some improvement:  for example, which macOS version are you using to build?  Which Xcode do you have installed (because there are command line tools available with them)?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann: I am using Mac OS Sierra version 10.12.6 and Xcode Version 8.3.3